# integration issue between Kafkaand OSB 12c

Tags: apache-kafka, osb

I am setting up connection between Kafka(kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0) and OSB 12c(12.2.1.2) , for consuming messages at OSB from kafka.

I have followed the required steps to install Kafka Transport in OSB and that is working succesfully, but when i am trying to consume messages from Kafka i am getting below Error :

> com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
>   consumer
>           at oracle.ateam.sb.transports.kafka.KafkaEndpoint.start(KafkaEndpoint.java:505)
>           at oracle.ateam.sb.transports.kafka.KafkaTransportProvider$EndpointsStartupTask.run(KafkaTransportProvider.java:399)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
>   consumer
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:587)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:569)
>           at oracle.ateam.sb.transports.kafka.KafkaEndpoint$InternalConsumer.(KafkaEndpoint.java:568)
>           at oracle.ateam.sb.transports.kafka.KafkaEndpoint.start(KafkaEndpoint.java:480)
>           ... 3 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Configuration was registered
>   that can handle the configuration named KafkaClient
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:86)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:83)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:623)
>           ... 7 more

I have tried creating new topic to read the messages from there but it is still not working.

configuration at OSB:

```
Transport:
Protocol : Kafka
endpoint URI: http://localhost:2181
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the endpoint you are using. There are two things that need to be fixed here:

1. Kafka doesn't use the **http** protocol, unless you're using REST Proxy.
2. The OSB transport for Kafka needs to point to the bootstrap servers.

Your endpoint seems to be pointing to Zookeeper, given the port **2181**.

Answer (score 0):

Here You are using the Zookeeper port (2181),
Instead Use Kafka bootstrap broker: **localhost:9092**